# error: "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception", errorcode: "42" Custom Grid Magento 2.3.5

Tags: error, grid, custom, uicomponent, magento2.3.5

I have created 10 columns. If I am using 9 columns then the grid is
loading, but once I enable 10th column it's giving an error:

```
error:"UI component could not be rendered because of system exception",errorcode: "42"
```

[image]

Here when i am adding 10th column
`average_orders_peryear` then

```
error:"UI component could not be rendered because of system exception",
errorcode: "42"
```

---

Below is my uiComponent listing file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- Integration -->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- we define a provider -->
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing_data_source</item>
            <!-- same string as above -->
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>

        <!-- define column type -->
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_columns</item>

    </argument>
    <!-- Data source -->
    <dataSource name="customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">CustomerlifetimeValueReportGridDataProvider</argument> <!-- Data provider class -->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing_data_source</argument> <!-- provider defined above -->
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument> <!-- Primary key -->
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument> <!-- URL name parameter -->

            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Primary key column name -->
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- Container Listing Top -->
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <!-- <columnsControls name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </columnsControls> -->
        
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
       <!--  <exportButton name="export_button" /> -->
          <!-- Paging -->
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_listing.customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
        
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>                          
                        </item> 
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>

    </container>

    <!-- Columns -->
    <columns name="customerlifetimevalue_report_customerlifetimevalue_columns" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo">
       <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        
         <column name="customer_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        
        
        <column name="customer_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
                <label translate="true">Customer ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        
        <column name="city" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo" sortOrder="30">
             <settings>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        
        
        
        <column name="postcode" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo" sortOrder="40">
             <settings>
                    <filter>false</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Postcode</label>
             </settings>
        </column>
        
        
        
        <column name="country" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Country</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        

        <column name="number_of_orders" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="60">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Total orders</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        
        <column name="first_order_purchase_date" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Date of first purchase</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        

        <column name="last_order_purchase_date" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Last order date</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        

        <column name="order_total" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Total orders value</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="average_order_total" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="100">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <label translate="true">Average order value</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        
        <column name="average_orders_peryear" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Metainfo"  sortOrder="110">
            <settings>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <sorting>desc</sorting>
                        <label translate="true">Average orders per year</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerlifetimeValue\Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerlifetimeValue;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\CustomerlifetimeValue', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerlifetimeValue');
    }
    
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        
         $this->addFilterToMap('entity_id', 'main_table.entity_id');

         $sales_order = $this->getTable('sales_order');
        
         $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['sales_order' => $sales_order],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.customer_id',
            [
                'sales_order.customer_id','main_table.*'
            ]
        )->group('sales_order.customer_id')->order('main_table.entity_id','DESC'); 
        
        return $this;
    } 
}
```

Error below:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'average_orders_peryear' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_order`.`customer_id`, `main_table`.* FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.customer_id GROUP BY `sales_order`.`customer_id` ORDER BY `main_table`.`entity_id` ASC, average_orders_peryear DESC LIMIT 20
```

In above error 10th columns `average_orders_peryear` also printing query.

By reviewing the above code if any idea please answer.

Comment: getting solution ???

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index fulltext into your schema.

See related post: [How to enable Full Text search in admin grid of magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87168/how-to-enable-full-text-search-in-admin-grid-of-magento2)